# PNG fix for sprites?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few buttons on my page that are styles using sprites, in ie6 however with the 'UNIT Png fix' http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php my sprites no longer work and there stretched to fit the container, Doesn anybody know if there's a png fix out there to work with sprites? Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you still supporting IE6?

Comment: @MrSlayer: There are application fields (e.g. process monitoring displays in industrial facilities) where you can't upgrade your browser with a click. These boxes need to go through a system test every time you change their software. So, one browser is deployed on these machines (maybe unfortunately IE6) and you'll have that browser for -- literally -- decades...

Comment: what @eckes says is true. Many companies have legacy intranets that work in a specific version of IE only thus don't allow upgrades. Perhaps if he's asking about it, means that he has a reason to support it :) - and yes - it sucks! but we have to live with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can fall back to a gif sprite background for IE6.

```
.myClass {
  background-image: url(img.png);
}

.ie6 .myClass {
  background-image: url(img.gif);
}
```

you can get the `.ie6` class on your `<body>` by following the html5boilerplate approach.

http://html5boilerplate.com/

EDIT

or add the IE6 override to a conditional css file:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie6.css" /><![endif]-->
```

credit to @lucideer, see comment below

Comment: As an alternative to the - rather ugly - html5boilerplate approach, you can also do this:

   `<!--[if lte IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie6.css" /><![endif]-->`   

This has the added advantage that other browsers don't have to download and parse IE-only styles.

Comment: I guess we could argue for days about this :) I prefer the "ugly" html5bp because it allows me to get rid of conditional stylesheets thus avoid one extra http request, and all the css is together - sometimes could be a pain to find related overrides that are in a separate files, especially knowing how ugly the dev toolbar is on IE6.. anyway fair point conditional comments are another option for sure ;)

Comment: @luca the extra http-request is only true when you use IE6 - with the IE6styles integrated into your normal css you have to deliver tons of "dead code" each time. NOt to mention is clutters your css up and you need an extra ugly class on the body tag...

Comment: @Christoph it really depends, if you do not have too many ie-specific hacks, there won't be too much clutter or "dead code". I believe that there is no perfect solution for every case - it depends on the project, and perhaps is easier to migrate all your ie-specific css to a separate file once the amount of hacks grow, rather than the opposite. Anyway, I've edited my answer to include both options!

Comment: @Christoph also one less http request for IE(6) could be useful if you have a few more to load js polyfills and other stuff like that - but once again is a matter of personal choice I guess.

Comment: @Luca sure, but you got my upvote anyways for mentioning both methods.

Comment: @Christoph Cheers! I should share that with lucideer who mentioned the second method - as they are both valid, I had to add them both in my answer from the beginning, regardless of my personal preference! :)

Comment: Apologies for the "ugly" comment - it is of course personal preference. You can also - inversely - lessen the load on IE6 (or other IEs) by doing the following with some of your more complex styles `<!--[if gt IE6]>--><link rel="stylesheet" href="fancy-progressive-enhancements.css" /><!--<![endif]-->`

If you're auto-concatenating your CSS into one file on the server-side you can also use this to selective auto-compiled version.

Comment: @lucideer no apologies needed mate - your point was very valid!

Answer (score 0):

In short, no there isn't. I ran into the same issue recently and I just created a GIF from the standard PNG and used an IE6 stylesheet to use the GIF. That way sprite positioning is still supported. This solution's viability depends on your design and how much transparency is needed. In some cases you can put the background in the gif where necessary, but I personally wouldn't worry too much about IE6